# Remote server(Bitbucket) returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: powershell, rest, basic-authentication, bitbucket-api

Making a rest service call in a Powershell script return following Exception

*Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."*
If I add the Rest URL directly in the Browser it do return all my repositories in json-format. Any hint to the reason.

```
$Global:TEAM = "team"
$Global:USER = "user@bitbucket.com"
$Global:PASSWORD = "password"

if (!$TEAM) {
 "Missing team"
} else {
    $storageDir = $pwd
    $webclient = new-object System.Net.WebClient
        $nexturl = "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/$TEAM"
        $cred = "$($USER):$($PASSWORD)"
        $enc_cred = [convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($cred))
        $webclient.Headers.Add("Authorization","Basic $enc_cred")
        Do {
        $webpage = $webclient.DownloadString($nexturl)        
        Write-Host $webpage
        $teamrepos = ConvertFrom-Json $webpage  
        Write-Host $teamrepos
            ForEach($val in $teamrepos.values) {
                        git clone $val.links.clone[1].href
            }
        $nexturl = $teamrepos.next
        } While($nexturl)
    "Done"
}
```